# Can't upload file to Document Library using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, asmx, csom, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am trying to upload multiple file to a Document Library and also update its coloumn values.
List(Doc Lib) already exists but I am stuck with uploadinf the file

I've tried these methods

1. using lists.asmx

   ```
           NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "Pass", "domain");
           #region ListWebService
           ListService.Lists listService = new ListService.Lists();
           listService.Credentials = credentials;
           List list = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(library);
           listService.Url = cc.Url + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
           try
           {
               FileStream fStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);
               string fName = fStream.Name.Substring(3);
               byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
               fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
               fStream.Close();

               string attach = listService.AddAttachment(library, itemId.ToString(), Path.GetFileName(filePath), contents);

           }
           #endregion


           catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
           {
               CSVWriter("Message:\n" + ex.Message + "\nDetail:\n" +
                   ex.Detail.InnerText + "\nStackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace, LogReport);
           }
   ```

It gives a error `ServerException :To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()` on `AddAttachment()`

2. Using

   ```
           List lib = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLib");
            FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
            fileInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\AJohn\\Desktop\\sample.docx");
            fileInfo.Url = "https://serverm/sites/Testing1/TestLib/sample.docx";
            fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File upFile = lib.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
            cc.Load(upFile);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();
   ```

I was able to upload `once` using this method, but now I am getting `ServerException :To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()` on `cc.ExecuteQuery()`

But if at all this method works, what I want is that I should update the coloumn values related to this file. In first method I get item.ID so from there I can update the Coloumn Values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the second method, the following example demonstrates how to upload a file into Documents library and set it's properties (e.g. `Category` text field)

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     var targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
     var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation
     {
          Url = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourcePath),
          Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath),
          Overwrite = true
     };

     var file = targetList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
     var item = file.ListItemAllFields;
     item["Category"] = "User Guide";
     item.Update();
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vandim it worked..and I was able to update the coloumns via CSV,  Any idea how to download full list (with coloumn values) into a csv  ?

Comment: @AndyCrz, it sounds to me like a good question, would you mind to create a separate question for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33266404/sharepoint-uploading-files-with-column-values-cant-load-taxonomy-fields-in-ta   here